# Libgdx, scale sizes based on device screen

Tags: android, libgdx

I am working on my first libgdx app, a game. I have made some apps in IntelliJ before, but this is different. I am struggling with how my game will look over several devices, how to make everything scale appropriately. 
If you can take a look at how I have it now, and maybe help me understand how it 'should' be to get the most out of it?

I have three classes, 'MyGame', 'MainMenuScreen' and 'GameScreen'.

```
// MyGame.java
    WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

// MainMenuScreen
public void show(){
    WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
}

// GameScreen
public void show(){
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
}
```

So, the 800, 480 is pixels, lets say I want to add something to this, and make it 32x32px (height, width), will it look the same on all devices? Bigger on large screens, and smaller on small screens, but always relevant to, lets say a background that is 800x480px?

I hope you understand what I am getting at. I posted the code I thought was relevant to the question, if u want more code, just say so, just tell me what you need.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: That looks like it could help, thanks!